# Sinatra App get request not connecting to sub directory views

Tags: ruby, project, sinatra-activerecord

I am building my first Sinatra App and I am having some issues connecting my controller to some of the sub directory views I have in place. It currently can go to review_entries but will not find any of the sub locations under review_entries.

```
     get 'review_entries/new' do
        #redirect_if_not_logged_in
        erb :'review_entries/new'
     end
```

[Here is the current setup for my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64iRI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add / to my get for the route so it couldnt traverse.

```
get '/review_entries/new'
```